# Drawing aplication HTML5 canvas, problems with touch events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I made this drawing application as an exercise but now I want to reuse the code for a project but my problem is that I need touch events (for ipad) instead of mouse events.

I tried with jquery mobile but I can not get the X and Y correctly.

Here the live demo: http://somnum.net/escenario-digital/dibujo_app/

Here the code:

```
var color = $(".selected").css("background-color");
var $canvas = $("canvas");
var context = $("canvas")[0].getContext("2d");

context.lineWidth = 2;
var lastEvent;
var mouseDown = false;


  $canvas.mousedown(function(e){

    lastEvent = e;
    mouseDown = true;

  }).mousemove(function(e){

    if(mouseDown){
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(lastEvent.offsetX, lastEvent.offsetY );
    context.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
    context.strokeStyle = color;
    context.stroke();
    lastEvent = e;
    }


  }).mouseup(function(){

    mouseDown = false;

  }).mouseleave(function(){

    $canvas.mouseup();
  });
```

Thank you.

Comment: The HTML5 canvas supports touch events, you will have to add them as an event handler.

Comment: I tried with touch events like "touchstart" instead of mousedown, the event works fine but my problem is with the line "context.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);"